# How to redirect Bootstrap carousel to another url?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a URL on clicking the next Bootstrap carousel button. So, when someone clicks the carousel indicator to view the slides a third time, it takes them to another URL. Here is my code along with the CSS code:

```css
.dropdown {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#textColor {
  color: #4b617d;
}

.bg-faded {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.carousel-control {
  color: #bada55;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url('download.png');
}


/* Carousel Header Styles */

.header-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: auto;
  width: 96.66666666666666%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header-text2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: auto;
  width: 96.66666666666666%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header-text3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: auto;
  width: 96.66666666666666%;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  right: 105px;
  bottom: 1px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-text h3 span {
  padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: 3px 1.2rem !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 3rem !important;
  width: 110px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #rightcol {
    margin-left: 12px;
  }
}

.d-block {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}

.header-text h4,
h5 {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.header-text h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-text2 h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-text3 h4,
h5 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-text2 h4,
h5 {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.header-text3 h4,
h5 {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11" style="padding-left: 0px;">
      <h5 id="textColor" style="margin-left: 12px;">Consecteteur Eliptois eliot</h5>
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
              <!-- Static Header -->
              <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <h4><span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /></h4>
                  <h5>Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /header-text -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide" style="padding-right:6px;">
              <!-- Static Header -->
              <div class="header-text2 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <h5>
                    <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /header-text -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid img-responsive" src="carouselbox.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <!-- Static Header -->
              <div class="header-text3 hidden-xs" id="secondslide">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <h5>
                    <span><strong>Image1</strong></span><br /> Lorem Ipsum
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /header-text -->
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Since you don't include the CSS or JavaScript you have so far, it's impossible to answer this question in its current state. Please add everything to the stack snippet to reproduce the image by [edit]ing your question to make this a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry posted above is the CSS for the above html code

Comment: You need to [edit] your question, like I said. You can't just post that in a comment.

Comment: ok I added the CSS code as well to the JS fiddle. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in jQuery and Bootstrap as well. The question still does not satisfy the condition of a [mcve], as it does not reproduce the carousel in the image, but it might be possible that someone knows how to answer it at this point. I will be honest, in the form this question is in, it's unlikely that someone will take the time to try and answer it, since an answer can't be verified that it will work with what you have.

Comment: I also checked and dont think the other posts talk about linking thew carousel to a page